# WMI Permissions for windows 7 standard user

Tags: .net, windows-7, wmi, serial-port

I have an .NET application that uses WMI to enumerate serial ports and find a device with a specific product id.  The application runs fine when logged in as an administrator, but I need it to run on a Windows 7 machine as a standard user.

I have tried running it as administrator.  Doesn't work.
I have added the user to the administrator group.  Doesn't work.
I have changed all the security settings from the WMI control. Doesn't work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my WMI code.

```
    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
            new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\WMI",
            "SELECT * FROM MSSerial_PortName");

        foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("MSSerial_PortName instance");
            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("PortName: {0} : Instance: {1} ", queryObj["PortName"], queryObj["InstanceName"]);
            string instanceName = (string)queryObj["InstanceName"];

            if (instanceName.Length > 0 && instanceName.Contains("6001"))
            {
                return (string)queryObj["PortName"];
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you set the `Root\WMI` namespace permissions for the specified user?

Comment: I did. I enabled all of the permissions just to be sure but I didn't have any luck.

Comment: I currently do not have access to a windows 7 machine to get the exact error but it was a System.Management.ManagementException ; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementexception.aspx

Comment: It wasn't an access denied exception though.

Comment: Do we know what the actual message present in the System.Managment.ManagmentException was?

Comment: I will report it as soon as I can.  My employer does not have a windows 7 machine in the office.  I will have to try it at home.  Developing in xp, deploying in windows 7 != ideal